# C# WPF | Cannot locate resource 'mainwindow.xaml'

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have been working on a project (C# WPF .NET Framework) for a while now and have got a problem and I
have already tried multiple things to try fix the issue when I build it is successful however

when I try to start/run the wpf it shows in Break Mode:

```
Cannot locate resource 'mainwindow.xaml
```

(Full: System.IO.IOException: 'Cannot locate resource 'mainwindow.xaml'.')

For my wpf I renamed everything to MainScreen:

```
<Window x:Class="***************.MainScreen"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:***************"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainScreen" Height="450" Width="800"
        AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent"
        WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize" FontSize="20" 
         >
```

If any of you need more information please add a comment with what you need.
Also I did the *'s because this project and name will be used officially, sorry and I hope you can understand.

Comment: I would look at your `App.xaml` that has a `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"`

Comment: You renamed mainwindow to mainscreen.  Either rename it back or change app.xaml so it's loading MainScreen.xaml instead if the default MainWindow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In App.xaml, make sure `StartupUri="MainScreen.xaml"` is set up correctly.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped!